# MVC4 Web application JQuery plug in

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have an empty ASP.Net MVC4 web application and I want to add a jquery tablesorter. I have added the script below to my view which contains the table but am unsure as to where I need to place the references to the jquery.tablesorter.pager.js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $("#mytable").tablesorter(); 
    }
); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give some feedback, we ended up going with the standard Jquery mobile lists.